# USB becomes unreadable after putting the .img on it-Mac

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive, mac, iso

I am trying to put Ubuntu on my USB to install it on my MacBook Pro, but after following step 8 of [this Ubuntu guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) it becomes unreadable and it doesn't show up while rebooting my computer and holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>. A message pops up that says "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer." directly after I finish the 8th step

How do I get my USB to become readable so I can test Ubuntu on my computer?

Comment: What do you mean when you say *unreadable*? That it is not recognized? You can't see the content of this device any more?

Comment: The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer. It seems like mac can not read ext4.Did you get the error after you logged into your desktop?

Comment: If I don't erase and reformat my drive, the message will keep popping up, but the first time it appears is after the 8th step

Comment: I have tried to just boot up my computer with the drive in, while holding alt, but the drive doesn't show up

Comment: A. What is the number version of your MacBook Pro. B. In the popup message did it ask to "initialize" the drive or anything like that. Also a picture of the partition tab of Disk Utility of the drive with the partition highlighted may help.